A question on the proof of unique continuation for the case $u\in H^{2}$ in Le Rousseau, Lebeau and Robbiano book on Carleman estimates
In the book Elliptic Carleman Estimates and Applications to Stabilization and Controllability, Volume I, page 186 (MR4436025, Zbl 1497.35005),  the authors proves a unique continuation theorem which is the argument of this question.
In the following $P=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\partial_{i}(p_{ij}\partial_{j}\cdot)$ is a second order partial differential operator and the coefficient $p_{ij}$ is smooth.
Theorem 5.2. Let $\Omega$ be a connected open subset in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and let $\omega\subset\Omega$, with $\omega\neq\emptyset$. If $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)$ satisfies$$|Pu(x)|\leq C\Big(|u(x)|+|Du(x)|\Big),\quad,a.e.\quad in\Omega$$
for some $C>0$ and $u(x)=0$ in $\omega$, then $u$ vanishes in $\Omega$.
Sketch of Proof: the authors set $F=\operatorname{supp}(u)$ (so $F$ is a closed set according the definition of support set of function), and then they prove that $F$ is also open to get $F=\emptyset$ and thus $u=0$.
They take a point $x^{(1)}$ in $F\setminus \operatorname{int}(F)$ and work in order to get a contradiction by the following proposition (Proposition 5.1 in the book). Precisely, their proof of by contradiction is worked out by constructing a family of balls
$$
\mathscr{B}_{t}=B\big(x^{(0)},(1-t)r_{1}+tr_{2}\big)
$$ where $x^{(0)}\in\Omega\setminus F$, and then proving (according to the said proposition) that if u vanishes in $\mathscr{B}_{t}$ with $0\leq t\leq1$, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $u$ vanishes in $\mathscr{B}_{t+\epsilon}$.
Here, we just know $B(x^{(0)};r_{1})\subset\Omega\setminus F$ in which $u=0$: now the question is how can we push the radius from $r_{1}$ to $r_{2}$?
The $\epsilon$ in each step is different, so how does there exist such a situation, that in each step, the increase of radius is$\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{10^{2}},\frac{1}{10^{3}},\dots$ so that we can not intersect $B(x^{(0)};r_{2})$?
Is it just as in ordinary differential equation, when we study the extension of classical solution of $\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t))$? Everytime we extend a little, but how the total step is finite?
Proposition 5.1. Let $u\in H^{2}_{\rm loc}(\Omega)$ and $$|Pu(x)|\leq C\Big(|u(x)|+|Du(x)|\Big),\text{ a.e.  in }\Omega$$ for some $C>0$ and $u(x)=0$ in $\{x\in V;\phi(x)\geq\phi(x^{(0)})\}$. Then $u$ vanishes in a neighborhood of $x^{(0)}$.
Remark, the author didn't tell us how large of the neighborhood is.

@WillieWong，thank you for your correction about some explanations!

@DanieleTampieri thank you for correcting my poor English explanation

Thank you for posting such interesting questions, monotone operator.

@DanieleTampieri, You are wellcome, you correct my bad paragraph, which help a lot!

I think one can answer your question (specifically the bold parts of your text) without having any knowledge of the precise argument of Lebeau; if you find the answer lacking, please let me know and also include a bit more detail (precise Theorem statements etc) since I don't have access to Lebeau's book at the moment.
With that in mind, I shall assume you accept the statement

If $u$ vanishes in $\mathscr{B}_t$, then $u$ vanishes in $\mathscr{B}_{t+\epsilon}$.

In this case, let $t_0 \in [0,1]$ be defined to be
$$ \sup \big\{ t\in [0,1] : u \text{ vanishes on } \mathscr{B}_t \big\} $$
The supremum exists as the set is non-empty (you've accepted that $0$ belongs to said set), and is upper bounded (by $1$). I claim that $u$ vanishes on $\mathscr{B}_{t_0}$: this follows from the fact that $\mathscr{B}_{t_0} = \cup_{t\in [0,t_0)} \mathscr{B}_{t}$.
Now suppose $t_0 < 1$, then by the Proposition which you accept you must have $u$ also vanishes $\mathscr{B}_{t_0+\epsilon}$ which contradicts the definition of $t_0$.

The reason that this differs from the local existence theorem for ODEs is that in that case, the extension condition is

If $u$ is a solution on $[0,t]$, then $u$ is a solution on $[0,t+\epsilon)$.

(Note the difference between open and closed domains.) And we can analogously set
$$ t_0 = \sup \big\{ t : u \text{ is a solution on } [0,t] \big\} $$
But now we cannot claim $u$ is a solution on $[0,t_0]$ to use the local existence theorem, since the definition of $t_0$ only guarantees that $u$ is a solution on $[0,t]$ for every $t < t_0$ (note the strictly less symbol). And $\cup_{t < t_0} [0,t] = [0,t_0)$ and not $[0,t_0]$.

thank you for your answer, according to your explanation, Lebeau's argument is like the bootstrap in spirit, right?   Proposition5.1 tell us that if $u$ is equal to $0$ on one side of hypersurface then $u$ will also equal to $0$ on a small neighborhood of that hypersurface($u$ satisfy the above partial differential inequalities). Your explanation about the relation between the proof of Lebeau and extension of solution of ode is really excellent!

Yes. The analogy with bootstrap arguments is apt. In fact, it may be easier to think in terms of the "closed" case where the extension is $u = 0$ on $\overline{\mathscr{B}{t}}$ implies $u = 0$ on $\mathscr{B}{t+\epsilon}$. The difference exposed is then that $u = 0$ is a closed condition, and when $u$ is by assumption continuous, you have that $u$ vanishing on the open ball implies it vanishes on the closed ball. This inability to take closures is fundamentally what breaks when you look at the ODE case.

Thanks!@WillieWong, I get it. Your answers and comments are invaluable for me!
